# CQRS - Commands, Tenses

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I've been researching DDD & CQRS and I'm wondering about the correct way to present a scenario in which the application is actually being used to report what a user has already done (both in the user interface and in the command names).

Assuming I'm doing an application to track a user's activities and there are predefined set of valid activities: Swimming, Eating etc. Leaving aside the discussion about whether this domain is collaborative enough for CQRS or not (because, even if it isn't I'm sure there would be some very collaborative domains that lend themselves to similar semantic analysis), I'd like to know: On the user interface, do I present buttons that say 'Go Swimming', 'Eat' etc, with similarly named commands or do I rather use 'Report Swimming', 'Record Lunch' etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question. I would say the clue is in how you described the application

"used to *report* what a user has already done"

The button's purpose will to be report a past activity so the command should be named 'Report Swimming', and the event 'Reported Swimming'.

I have faced similar scenarios and have found, 'report' commands and 'reported' events work nicely

Comment: Thanks, @danielfishr. Sounds reasonable. I'll accept this if I do not get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are recording events. Things that have already happened and should be tracked somehow. Therefore you wouldn't send any commands at all. Just publish the respective events and handle them in your domain as needed.

Comment: Can the events be raised straight from the client?

Comment: Either that (if the client is a trusted source) or you can raise the events at the application service level. There is no rule that every event must come from within the domain model or that it must have a preceeding command. Events can come out of nowhere from the system's point of view. That's how it would integrate with external components anyway.

Comment: How does the domain receive those events? Apparently they're not coming from the command bus (for obvious reasons ;-)). Does that mean that there is - besides the command bus - also an event bus with an "event handler" that runs the domain, or …?

Comment: @GoloRoden Once different parts of your aplication (contexts, domains, services, you name it) communicate with each other through events they will need some means of handling these. This could happen on a per-service level (each service subscribing to events on a common bus) or on an orchestration level (sagas, process managers, business process engines, etc. outside the services).